# My DVD's Will Not Play?

Tags: dvd

I've loaded everything suggested and almost all the multimedia apps available, and my DVD's will not play.  The device is found, `/dev/sr0` as well as the required links to `/dev/dvd` (for some programs). Every lib...so has been found and installed.  The codecs are current.  Somethings missing still.

I removed and reloaded the addon's to MPlayer, Totem and several others. I added the Ubuntu Restricted (MP..., AVI etc) additions. I've removed and reloaded Totem, MPlayer, VLC and several others and reloaded the addon's and plugins again.

I verified that the links to the Devices are correct. I removed and reloaded the available codec's. Note: Those Videos I created on DVD from my BeOS System Play just fine. Further the digital copies play fine. It is only Original DVD's that are giving me fits. Windows Vista play them on an alternate boot drive.

Comment: can you confirm that you've tried this answer as well?  http://askubuntu.com/questions/500/how-can-i-play-encrypted-dvd-movies

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem with a DVD drive. Once I booted into Windows and played the DVDs, everything worked fine in Ubuntu. It was suggested that Windows set my drive's region, which is required to play DVDs.

I don't know if this is the case for you, but it's easy to set your region.

1. Insert the DVD into the drive without playing it or accessing it.
2. Install `regionset` from the Universe repositories.
3. Run `sudo regionset`.

More info [here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs#Setting%20DVD%20Region%20Codes)

Comment: regionset works... The address with 2 DVD players and a DVD Burner in this system needed to be changed. Thanks

Comment: That's good to hear.

Answer (score 0):

You're not saying which version of Ubuntu you're using. You're not saying what you've done. You're not saying which products you've tried.

This makes it very difficult to provide a good answer, but... Have you tried purchasing a legal DVD player? Fluendo DVD player is $25 in Ubuntu Software Center. DVD is special, you know.

Comment: I have the Fluendo Player.  I'm running Ubuntu 11.  Fluendo works part time on DVD's Older than 1998 or those I have made.  The should work on the others as well with all the codecs in place. I've paid the extra that we once didn't/shouldn't need!