# By what methods can I check information about a DVD video disc?

Tags: dvd

I have some DVD video discs that I am intending to sell.  I would like to get information such as region, language, subtitles.

Some of the discs are in another language which I cannot read, and some are from small publishers and do not have such information on the disc or the boxes.

What methods can I use to access this information?  Please list command line options, as well as common GUI based tools (eg VLC player).

Answer (score 5):

### VLC

You can go in VLC to **Tools --> Media Information** / **Tools --> Codec Information** to get a lot of information about the DVD. If you get any problems with the DVD, please make sure to read some of the following links:

[How can I play encrypted DVD movies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500/how-can-i-play-encrypted-dvd-movies)

[My DVD's Will Not Play?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58274/my-dvds-will-not-play)

[Discs in DVD Drive not being read](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47329/discs-in-dvd-drive-not-being-read)

### mediainfo

To Install:`sudo apt-get install mediainfo-gui mediainfo`
To Run: The GUI version is obviously **mediainfo-gui**. The terminal one is just `mediainfo`, which you can use in the following way:

`mediainfo -f SOURCE`. For example `mediainfo -f /media/cyrex/moviedvd`

### lsdvd

To Install: `sudo apt-get install lsdvd`

To Run:`lsdvd -x SOURCE`. For example `lsdvd -x /media/cyrex/moviedvd`

This are not all since typing **dvd* in the Software Center will give you many DVD players, editors, rippers, etc.. that most of them can give you information about your DVD.

[image]